# Moving audio books from Iphone to Android

Tags: encryption, android, iphone

I have a bunch of purchased audiobooks on my iphone and would like to move them to my android.  Problem is all of these books are encrypted and I have read that decrypting them is illegal.

I am using ubuntu 16, my two questions are:

1) Is it legal to decrypt these books and transfer them

2) If so, what is the best way to go about this

Comment: Your audiobooks seem to be protected by [Digital Rights Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) (DRM), so decrypting them would be a violation of DRM. Hence it is not legal to decrypt them.

Comment: What app were they purchased in?

Comment: they were purchased through itunes